# asp.net razor in webmatrix sql methods

Tags: sql, asp.net, razor, ado.net, asp.net-webpages

is there any problems with the (var query4) coz th aps desn't show me any msg but it can't insert the data into the table concerne

```
@{
    var userId = Request["UserId"];
    var Type = Request["type"];
    var db = Database.Open("intranet");
    if(Type == "delete")
    {

    var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = 'refuser' WHERE UserId = '" + userId + "'";
    db.Execute(query);

     var query2 = "DELETE from DemandeConge where UserId = '" + userId + "'";
    db.Execute(query2);
   }
    else if(Type == "accepte")
    {


        var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = 'accepte' WHERE UserId = '" + userId + "'";
        db.Execute(query);

        var query2 = "DELETE from DemandeConge where UserId = '" + userId + "'";
        db.Execute(query2);


        var query4 = "INSERT INTO CongeAccept(UserId,DateDebut,DateFin,TypeConge) SELECT UserId,DateDebutDemande,DateFinDemande,TypeConge FROM DemandeConge WHERE UserId = '" + userId + "'";
        db.Execute(query4);
    }
}
```

and whene i make the comment into this code it works as well :

```
   /* var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = 'accepte' WHERE UserId = '" + userId + "'";
    db.Execute(query);

    var query2 = "DELETE from DemandeConge where UserId = '" + userId + "'";
    db.Execute(query2);*/


    var query4 = "INSERT INTO CongeAccept(UserId,DateDebut,DateFin,TypeConge) SELECT UserId,DateDebutDemande,DateFinDemande,TypeConge FROM DemandeConge WHERE UserId = '" + userId + "'";
    db.Execute(query4);
}
```

Comment: **WARNING** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: yes i know its just an exercice fr the exam ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting everything from DemandeConge relating to the user you want to insert into CongeAccept so when the try the insert query, there is nothing there to insert. Change the order of your statements and use parameters:

```
@{
    var userId = Request["UserId"];
    var Type = Request["type"];
    var db = Database.Open("intranet");
    if(Type == "delete")
    {

    var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = 'refuser' WHERE UserId = @0";
    db.Execute(query, userId);

     var query2 = "DELETE from DemandeConge where UserId = @0";
    db.Execute(query2, userId);
   }
    else if(Type == "accepte")
    {
        var query = "UPDATE Personne SET Demande = 'accepte' WHERE UserId = @0";
        db.Execute(query, userId);

        var query4 = "INSERT INTO CongeAccept(UserId,DateDebut,DateFin,TypeConge) SELECT UserId,DateDebutDemande,DateFinDemande,TypeConge FROM DemandeConge WHERE UserId = @0";
        db.Execute(query4, userId);

        var query2 = "DELETE from DemandeConge where UserId = @0";
        db.Execute(query2, userId);
    }
}
```